# Is the space of bounded and continuous functions that are 0 at the integers separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

So let be $E$ the following
$$E=\left\{x\in C_{b}(\mathbb{R}) : x(k)=0, k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}. $$
I know that $E$ is closed in $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$. Is that enough to say that $E$ is or is not separable, hence $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ isn't?

Comment: As @orangeskid points out, there's an embedding of $\ell^\infty(\mathbf Z)$ into $C_b(\mathbf R)$. There's also an embedding $\ell^\infty(\mathbf Z)$ into $E$. If $A$ embeds into $B$ and $A$ is inseparable, i.e. no countable subset is dense, then $B$ too must fail to be separable.

Comment: For any $S\subset \mathbb Z$ \ $\{0\}$  there exists $ f_S\in C_b(\mathbb R)$ such that $\forall x\in S\;(f_S(x)=1)$ and $\forall x\in \mathbb Z \backslash S\;(f_S(x)=0).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any subset of a separable metric space is separable. So, showing $E$ is inseparable would show $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is inseparable. Showing $E$ is separable won't show you that $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is separable or inseparable (or at least, it won't without some extra work).

Comment: So knowing $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$  is inseparable and that $E$ is closed in $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ won't help to say that $E$ is inseparable or separable? I want to know if $E$ is separable or not.

Comment: @MartinG Correct. As extreme examples, $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ and is (presumably) inseparable, whereas $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is closed in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ and is separable.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$l_{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$ is imbedded into $C_b(\mathbb{R})$, the first is not separable, so neither is the other one.

$\bf{Added:}$ For every function $\chi$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{0,1\}$ there exists a (bounded) continuous function $f_{\chi}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$ (say interpolate linearly between integers).We get an uncountable family of functions $(f_{\chi})_{\chi}$ so that the distance between any two of them is $1$, and so, an uncountable family  of open balls $B(f_{\chi}, \frac{1}{3})$ that are pairwise disjoint. It follows that $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable.